# How to select rows from a data frame based on the values in a table of ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, range, pandas-groupby

I have a table of ranges `(start,end)`:

```
name     blue         green          yellow        purple              
a        1,5                         654,678       11,15
b                     88761,88776  
c        1211,1215                   38,47    
d        89,95                                     1567,1578
```

And a data frame like this:

```
Supplier        colour                   
Abi             1                               
John            678          
Smith           120               
Tim             1570 
Don             87560
```

How can I filter the `df` to contain only rows whose values in the `colour` column are within the ranges provided in the table? I'd like the final `df` to look like this:

```
Supplier        colour                   
Abi             1                               
John            678                         
Tim             1570
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Firstly replace `' '` to `NaN` via `replace()` method:

```
df1=df1.replace(r'\s+',float('NaN'),regex=True)
                  #^ it will replace one or more occurence of ' '
```

The idea is to make the string ranges to actual list of combined range values:

```
s=df1.set_index('name').stack().dropna() 
s=s.str.split(',').map(lambda x:range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)).explode().unique()
```

Finally:

```
out=df2[df2['colour'].isin(s)]
#OR
out=df2.loc[df2['colour'].isin(s)]
```

output of `out`:

```
    Supplier    colour
0   Abi          1
1   John        678
3   Tim         1570
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your time! And apologies for my late acknowledgement of your answer. I've spent the last hour trying to figure out what this error message means after I ran your code, and I still haven't figured out how to fix it. I got this: ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '```

Comment: @cave again updated answer....kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Hi there, please how can I edit the code to get a third column in the output file ```out```. The third column could be named ```source``` for example. In the third column, the value for row ```Abi``` would be ```a-blue```, the column value for ```John``` would be ```a-yellow```, and value for ```Tim``` would be ```d-purple```. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @cave pls wait let me see

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your time! Could you please revert your code back to the original question I asked, I've been advised to ask a new question so as not to confuse other people. Here's the link to the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68469939/how-to-map-values-of-a-data-frame-to-the-row-and-column-header-of-another-data-f

Answer (score 1):

Try using a list comprehension and `loc`:

```
l = [x for i in df1[df1.columns[1:]].values.flatten().tolist() if ',' in str(i) for x in range(int(i.split(',')[0]), int(i.split(',')[1]) + 1)]
print(df2.loc[df2['colour'].isin(l)].reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
     Supplier        colour                   
0    Abi             1                               
1    John            678                         
2    Tim             1570
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your time! And apologies for my late acknowledgement of your answer. I've spent the last hour trying to figure out what this error message means after I ran your code, and I still haven't figured out how to fix it. I got this: ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '```

Comment: Thanks! I no longer get the error message. But the output you got is not the same as the output that I want. The output I want is ```1```, ```678``` and ```1570```. But yours is ```678```, ```120```, and ```87560```. When I remove ```~``` from the ```print``` statement, I got ```1```, and ```1570```

Comment: @cave Edited my answer should work now sorry

Comment: ```678``` is missing. But it should be included as well

Comment: I got only ```1``` when I used the edited code. Now, ```678``` and ```1570``` are missing.

Comment: @cave Another typo thanks for catching, now it should work, pls upvote and accept if it does

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235138/discussion-between-cave-and-u11-forward).

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.cut` and `pd.IntervalIndex`:

```
tups = table.set_index('name').unstack() \
            .replace(r'\s+', float('nan'), regex=True).dropna() \
            .apply(lambda x: tuple([int(i) for i in x.split(',')])).values

ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(tups, closed='both')

out = supplier.loc[pd.cut(supplier['colour'], ii).dropna().index]
```

```
>>> out
  Supplier  colour
0      Abi       1
1     John     678
3      Tim    1570
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your time! And apologies for my late acknowledgement of your answer. I've spent the last hour trying to figure out what this error message means after I ran your code, and I still haven't figured out how to fix it. I got this: ```ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '```